# How to use nested functions in r with different arguments?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write some functions in R where, i have defined a few functions and these functions take different arguments. 
Example, i have defined these two functions, foo1 & foo2 -

```
foo1 <- function(x,y){
  return((x+y)*foo2(p,q))
}

foo2 <- function(p,q){
 return(p*q)
}
```

Now, i want to use these functions inside a wrapper function foo3 -

```
foo3 <- function(x,y,p,q){
 return(foo1(x,y))
}
```

But when i call

```
foo3(1,2,3,4)
```

i get the following error - 
Error in foo2(p, q) : object 'p' not found

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: how would `foo1` know where to get p and q to pass them to `foo2`?

Comment: i understand the problem i am making, but not sure how to resolve this. I don't want to define same arguments for all the functions

Comment: can you elaborate on that, why not, for example, use p and q as arguments for  `foo1`?

Comment: i can add p & q as additional arguments to foo1 and then my code will run just fine, but i have a lot of functions like this and don't want to duplicate arguments for each function.

Comment: you could use the three dots notation e.g. `foo1(x, y, ...){return((x+y)*foo2(...))}`